# Swift push notifications delegate debug mode behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have APNS connected to my app.

The problem is in different behavior of system delegate `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. It is working properly only when the debugger is attached to the app, otherwise, it is not called when the app is in the background state. For example, the delegate is called if test phone is connected to the mac via USB cable and app is being debugged. Right after cable disconnection delegate is not called anymore.

The question is how app state (debugged or not) influence on `didReceiveRemoteNotification` behavior. (both IOS 10 and 11)

To detect delegate call I make backend requests and I'm sure there is no problem with call detection.

Comment: What method did you implement ? `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` or `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` ?

Comment: I have both of them implemented and trying to detect call from both of them. none working either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, spent a lot of time looking for a solution. I found a [workaround mentioned in the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79734#272007).

Make the class where you handle the push notifications a delegate of `UNUserNotificationCenter`

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
```

and then implement the `willPresent notification: UNNotification` method

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension APNSService: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        Log.debug?.message("Received push in foreground through UserNotificationCenter, calling Inbox.incrementalSync")
        ...        
        completionHandler([])
    }
}
```